# There does not exist a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ with $|S_n:H|=n$ and $H$ does not fix any element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> For $n\in \mathbb N$ consider the symmetric group $S_n$ as the group of all bijections from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ onto itself. Then the following is impossible: There exists a subgroup $H$ of $S_n$ with
> $|S_n:H|=n$ and $H$ does not fix any element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

How should I approach ?

My effort: Consider the action of $H$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Note that there is no fixed points. Every orbit has $(n-1)!$ elements. If there are $k$ orbits then $k\cdot(n-1)!=n$, i.e., $k=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$. For $n>2$, $k$ fails to be an integer.

Sorry my arguments are wrong, orbits are not necessarily of same size.

Comment: Where did this question come from? Looks like you pasted it in, is it homework?

Comment: No No.. I was looking at this problem..https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472977/maximal-subgroup-of-s-n$. Then I asked myself this question.

Comment: How have you got so many reputation points and yet ask a PSQ like this?

Comment: I thought of applying the natural action of H on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and looking at the orbit stabilizer theorem...but no result... May be I have to look at the group morphism from $S_n$ to $S_n$ whose kernel is a subgroup of $H$ and then cotradict.

Comment: I can't prove that it is not a homework problem either.

Comment: Reason for downvote is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me. But often things get downvoted when, as yours, no effort to solve in original.

Comment: @Shaun If it is that trivial a question please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: No, PSQ stands for "**P**roblem **S**tatement **Q**uestion". It has little to do with the difficulty of the question.

Comment: Incidentally this result does not hold when $n=6$. The triply transitive group ${\rm PGL}(2,5)$ has index $6$ in $S_6$. In general, a subgroup of $S_n$ of index $n$ that did not fix a point would imply the existence of an outer automorphism of $S_n$, so the result follows from the fact that no such outer automorphism exists for $n \ne 6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As basically pointed out by Derek Holt in the comments, if $H < S_n$ is a subgroup such that $[S_n : H] = n$, then the left coset action on $H$ gives you a homomorphism $\varphi: S_n \rightarrow S_n$.

Show that $\varphi$ is an automorphism.

If $H$ is transitive, show that $\varphi$ must be an outer automorphism.

Conclude that $n = 6$.

Then at this point I suppose you have to look at $S_6$ more closely to conclude that the only possibility is $H = PGL(2,5)$. Some hints are in Dixon and Mortimer, Chapter 2, Exercise 2.9.8.

Comment: In order to show that $\phi$ is an automorphism enough to show that $\phi$ is injective and  $\ker \phi$ is the intersection of all conjugates of $H$ in $S_n$. How can I show that it is trivial?

Comment: Well, the kernel is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, and we know what those are.

Comment: For $n=4$ also Klein's $4$ group, $K_4$ not subset of $H$, since $|H|=6$. Now it is clear that $\phi$ is an automorphism.

Comment: $H$ is transitive will imply that $\phi$ is not an inner automorphism. Can you give some sketch for this statement?

Comment: If $H$ is transitive, show that $H$ and $\varphi(H)$ are not conjugate in $S_n$.